# Can I add more metadata to my pdf?

Tags: metadata, pdfx

I use pdfx to generate the metadata of my document. Is there a way to generate more entries via the xmpdata file?

Entries I consider as relevant (as required for bibliography) are e.g. subtitle, institution for tech reports or school for theses.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}

\begin{filecontents}{test_pdfx.xmpdata}
\Title{Test PDF/A-2u standard}
\Subtitle{This subtitle is not added to the document}
\Author{Me T. Author}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Tested PDF/A-2u.

\end{document}
```

More bibliographic entries can be found at [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management).

## Applications

While reading the [manual of pdfx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf), I did not really understand what the `/Info` part of the meta data is used for. Where would I see an effect if I include \sep in title, authors or keywords?

Comment: Maybe hyperxmp package is what you are looking for.

Comment: For me it is important to generate a long-living PDF/A as output, so are they compatible. There is no word about incompatibility between pdfx and hyperxmp. If not Marijin's answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @strpeter `pdfx` and `hyperxmp` are incompatible, but `hyperxmp` can also generate PDF/A (as shown in my answer). Also, just one `i` (as in Mar**ij**n), I don't mind the mistake but if you want me to be notified using @-mentions then you should spell the name correctly :) see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work.

Answer (score 8):

There are two types of metadata: The entries in the info dictionary and the xmp-metadata. In PDF 2.0 the info dictionary is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

### Info dictionary

hyperref allows to add more entries to the info dictionary:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={Subtitle=some subtitle}}
\begin{document}
Tested
\end{document}
```

This entry can then be seen in the pdf properties:

[image]
But `pdfx` redefines an internal hyperref command and destroys such add-ons.

### xmp-metadata

xmp-metadata can be added with `pdfx` and `hyperxmp`, (the packages are incompatible, so you will have to choose). `pdfx` doesn't know a Subtitle-metadata and as far as I can see has also no interface to add new metadata. With `hyperxmp` you can add a subtitle-metadata, but as `hyperxmp` like `pdfx` overwrites an internal `hyperref` command this destroys the entry in the info dictionary too.
If you want to keep this you will have to resort to low-level primitives, e.g. with pdftex

```
\pdfinfo{/Subtitle (text)}
```

`text` must be a valid pdf-string or you must pass it through \pdfstringdef.

XMP-metadata are added automatically if you use the PDF management. See https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb43-3/tb135fischer-xmp.pdf and `texdoc l3pdfmeta` for more info.

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={Subtitle=some subtitle}}
\begin{document}
Tested
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that nowadays, PDF readers (and archives) prefer XMP metadata to the /info dictionary. If both are present, then duplicated keys must match. If they do not match, then XMP is preferred. Encoding for XMP is utf-8, but /info is either pdfdoc encoding or utf-16 (this is something that `hyperref` can do). Apparently the dates of creation and modification should be in /info, even if they are in XMP. What I do not know: Whether or not custom XMP entries must define a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, you can use the `hyperxmp` package. This allows for an extensive set of additional metadata fields to be entered, among which a subtitle field and various bibliographical information fields. Note that the extra information is not visible by default in the document properties dialog, it can be viewed using the <kbd>Additional Metadata...</kbd> button in Acrobat Pro.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle={Test PDF/A-2u standard},
pdfauthor={Me T. Author},
pdfsubtitle={Subtitle of the document},
pdfpubtype={Technical Report},
pdfpublisher={Scientific Institution of Tech Reports},
pdfapart={2},
pdfaconformance={U},
keeppdfinfo
}

\begin{document}

Tested PDF/A-2u.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the `pdfx` package is not used. The `pdf/a-2u` conformance is set by a combination of the `pdfa` option to `hyperref` and the `pdfapart` and `pdfaconformance` fields of `hyperxmp`. Note also that the `keeppdfinfo` option is specified, if this is not there then no metadata is shown at all in viewers other than Adobe Reader/Acrobat. With this option only the standard info is shown in other viewers (Evince, `pdfinfo` in the terminal, etc), not the additional metadata fields.

If you want to add a custom field that is not predefined by `hyperxmp` then you could use the `xmpincl` package. The manual of `hyperxmp` notes:

> `hyperxmp` and `xmpincl` can complement each other. An author may
>   want to use `hyperxmp` to produce a basic set of XMP code, then extract
>   the XMP code from the pdf file with a text editor, augment the XMP code with
>   any metadata not supported by `hyperxmp`, and use `xmpincl` to include the
>   modified XMP code in the pdf file.

Comment: Your example does not compile in my machine. It said that the keys from the package are undefined... I know I installed texlive-core, where the package is included. Eventually I need a newer version than 2018/11/27? For me it is important to generate a PDF/A as output, so I hope they are compatible.

Comment: Yes, there is a newer version (2019-04-07, see https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp) which has more keys. Installation is simple: go to [Sources](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperxmp) and download `hyperxmp.dtx` and `hyperxmp.ins`, then run `latex hyperxmp.ins` (note: regular latex, _not_ pdflatex). Then a `hyperxmp.sty` file is generated. If you place it in the same folder as your `.tex` file (or in your texmf tree to make it globally available) then LaTeX will use the new version instead of the system-installed version.